# Divisor: Show that $a|b \Rightarrow a|(b \cdot c)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> We have arbitrary $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$.
>
> $a|b$ means "a divides b", so actually it's equal to $\frac{b}{a}$ or
>   you say "there exists an $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a \cdot x = b$"
>
> (i) Is it true that $a|b \Rightarrow a|(b \cdot c)$?
>
> (ii) Is it true that $(a|b \text{ and } b|c) \Rightarrow a|c$?

I did (ii) and I think it's correct because it makes sense :p

(ii) $(a|b \text{ and } b|c) \Leftrightarrow \frac{b}{a} \text{ and } \frac{c}{b} = \frac{c}{a}$ which is $a|c$, so yes it's true.

But how to do (i) ? Did I even do (ii) correctly?

Comment: "actually it's equal to $\frac ba$"... *actually, no*. $\frac ba$ is a number. If you mean "$\frac ba\in\Bbb Z$", then this interpretation is almost correct, only that the expression "$0\mid a$" makes sense (and it is true if and only if $a=0$), while "$\frac{a}{0}\in\Bbb Z$" is meaningless whatever $a$ you pick.

Comment: Most of the time, it's preferable to avoid using fractions when working with integers. Instead, you could write : $a \times k = b$ and $b \times k' = c $ for $k,k' \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, it's straightforward to write $a \times k \times k' = b \times k' = c$ and $k\times k' \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $$a|b\iff b=ax\Rightarrow bc=axc\Rightarrow a|bc$$      $$a|b\text {and } b|c\iff b=ac\text {and } c=by\Rightarrow by=c=axy\Rightarrow a|c$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything follows from this logic of yours :

> $a|b$ means "a divides b", so actually it's equal to $\frac{b}{a}$ or
>   you say "there exists an $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a \cdot x = b$"

**(i).** For this problem, you can state that there exists an $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a \cdot x = b$. Or, in other words, $b \cdot c=a \cdot c \cdot x = a \cdot k$ where $k= c \cdot x$. SO we can conversely state that since there exists an $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $b \cdot c=a \cdot k$, then $a|b \cdot c$

**(ii).** For this one, you use the logic twice in succession. So you can write that $a \cdot x=b$ and $c=b \cdot y$ which imply that $c=a \cdot x \cdot y$ and similar reasoning follows, just like the above problem. So $a|c$.

I hope that you get it now.

Comment: Thanks, understood!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would approach this.

(i)Since a|b, therefore, b=ma, for some integer value m. So, bc=mac, and $\frac{bc}{a}=mc$, which is an integer. Thus, (i) is proved that it is true.

(ii)Using above idea, b=ma, and c=bn for integers m and n. So, c=man, and $\frac{c}{a}=mn$, which is an integer again. Hence, (ii) is true as well!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much too :)